# Sitecore Crawler : AddRecursive DoItemAdd failed

Tags: indexing, solr, sitecore, sitecore6

Our crawler log is filled with the following Index Out of Bounds Exception. Has anyone seen this error? Or have any ideas on how to resolve?

```
    4548 00:37:31 WARN  Crawler : AddRecursive DoItemAdd failed - {DDAFF741-80D0-4650-8E73-02A88EB2C8DC}
Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException
Message: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Caching.ItemPathsCache.UpdateKeyIndex(List`1 list, String value)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.AddOrUpdate(TKey key, TValue addValue, Func`3 updateValueFactory)
   at Sitecore.Caching.ItemPathsCache.AddMapping(Item item, ItemPathType itemPathType, String path)
   at Sitecore.Data.ItemPath.DoGetPath(Item currentItem, String separator, ItemPathType type, Item root, Int32 level)
   at Sitecore.Data.ItemPath.DoGetPath(Item currentItem, String separator, ItemPathType type, Item root, Int32 level)
   at Sitecore.Data.ItemPath.DoGetPath(Item currentItem, String separator, ItemPathType type, Item root, Int32 level)
   at Sitecore.Data.ItemPath.DoGetPath(Item currentItem, String separator, ItemPathType type, Item root, Int32 level)
   at Sitecore.Data.ItemPath.DoGetPath(Item currentItem, String separator, ItemPathType type)
   at Sitecore.Data.ItemPath.DoGetPath(Item currentItem, String from, String separator, ItemPathType type)
   at Sitecore.Data.ItemPath.GetPath(Item currentItem, String from, String separator, ItemPathType type)
   at Sitecore.Data.ItemPath.get_ContentPath()
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.DoAdd(IProviderUpdateContext context, SitecoreIndexableItem indexable)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.HierarchicalDataCrawler`1.CrawlItem(T indexable, IProviderUpdateContext context, CrawlState`1 state)
```

Comment: Hi, are you using any custom strategy or custom code concerning indexing?

Comment: Can you check item {DDAFF741-80D0-4650-8E73-02A88EB2C8DC}? What is that item's path? Any weird things about it?

Comment: Is it only for this item ID {DDAFF741-80D0-4650-8E73-02A88EB2C8DC} ? What sitecore version are you using?

Comment: @AhmedOkour It is happening for several items. We are using version 6.

Comment: @Gatogordo There is nothing unusual about the item's path.